# Why does this function returns size of array when there is no return statement?

Tags: c, function

I'm getting output as 8 for this program. Why is this function returning size of array when there is no return statement? It is working properly when I write the return statement but I'm still curious why this function is returning the size of array. I thought it should return garbage value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sumofelements(int A[],int size)
{
    int i,sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++) 
        sum = sum + A[i];
}

int main()
{
    int A[]={3,4,5,6,3,6,1,10};
    int size=sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);
    int total=sumofelements(A,size);
    printf("sum of the elements=%d",total);
}
```

Comment: you have whats called Undefined Behaviour. You have the worst kind, UB that appears to work. It will fail in production on the busiest day of the year.

Comment: Aman kumar, the returned value is a garbage value.  Why do you think it is not?

Comment: "busiest day of the year" ... two hours after you're gone to bed during the 2nd day of your vacation in Fiji.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is undefined. Any value is possible, including the observed behavior. And on some exotic architectures, a trap value might cause other strange behavior.

For your particular case, the place where `sumofelements` is expected by `main` to have placed its return value (some CPU register) happens to contain the value of `size`, but no guarantee whatsoever: it might not on a different combination of CPU/OS/compiler/set of options/time of day...

Use `gcc -Wall -Werror` or a similar warning level to avoid such silly mistakes.

You can look at the assembly and behavior on [Godbolt's Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/9h1qodfTa) and play with compiler flags and compiler versions to see how volatile the behavior is.  With `-O2`, both **gcc** and **clang** generate a simple `ret` instruction for `sumofelements` and do not even call this function for the `printf` call.

Answer (score 1):

Not explicitly returning a value from a non-void function (except `main()`) results in [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This means that anything can happen: a crash, returning garbage value, or **worse of all, the expected value!**

You should always return something (meaningful) from a non-void function.

Comment: It is not true that anything can happen. Even if you violate the rules of the C standard, the safeguards of the operating system still apply: The program cannot modify the private memory of other processes. The safeguards of consumer law still apply: The computer must not catch fire or cause other safety hazards. The C standard is merely one factor in how programs behave; it is not the ultimate ruler and does not say “anything can happen.” Students should learn there are many things controlling program behavior, not just the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Of course. "anything can happen: **a crash, returning garbage value, or worse of all, the expected value!**" Not the computer catching fire. I suppose the context here is within the program itself.

Comment: @EricPostpischil on my pdp11 and on my arduino it can pretty much stomp over everything  including the OS and the file system. I used to say "UB can do anything including turning on the xmas tree lights on the white house lawn, " you have taken that fun away now.

Answer (score -1):

Return values are picked from `eax` which is a register on your CPU (registers are like your CPU’s own place to store some small amounts of data outside of RAM) it happened to be that `eax` contained the size of the array just before your function ended.

Probably in `i < size`, `size` is stored in `eax` and is not modified any further until your function ends, but you would have to `objdump -d` your program and paste it here for me to say anything certain.

If you want to learn more type “CPU registers” and read some stuff online.

I will extend my answer just for the sake of doing it.

OK, I copied your code and compiled it using GCC MinGW and disassembled it using objdump. Now here is the disassembly:

```
<sumofelements>:
0000000000000000 <sumofelements>:
   0:   55                      push   rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    rbp,rsp
   4:   48 89 7d e8             mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18],rdi
   8:   89 75 e4                mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x1c],esi
   b:   c7 45 f8 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x0
  12:   c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x0
  19:   eb 1d                   jmp    38 <sumofelements+0x38>
  1b:   8b 45 fc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
  1e:   48 98                   cdqe
  20:   48 8d 14 85 00 00 00    lea    rdx,[rax*4+0x0]
  27:   00
  28:   48 8b 45 e8             mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x18]
  2c:   48 01 d0                add    rax,rdx
  2f:   8b 00                   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rax]
  31:   01 45 f8                add    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],eax
  34:   83 45 fc 01             add    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x1
  38:   8b 45 fc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
  3b:   3b 45 e4                cmp    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x1c]
  3e:   7c db                   jl     1b <sumofelements+0x1b>
  40:   90                      nop
  41:   5d                      pop    rbp
  42:   c3                      ret
```

If you examine the disassembly you can see that the last modification of `eax` was at the 38th byte, after that the loop ends and we return. This line in particular

```
mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
```

is the line before the loop checks for `i < size`. The line moves `[rbp-0x4]` to `eax`. If we go back to the start of the program, we can see that `[rbp-0x4]` is `i`.

Considering all of this, everything makes sense. For the loop to end `i < size` must resolve to `false`. Since `size` is 8, `i` must also be 8 for the loop to end. The value of `i` is moved into `eax` to check if it smaller than `size` and at the iteration that the loop ends `i` would have the value of 8 and therefore `eax` would also be 8. The loop ends and we return what is in eax. So as a matter of fact it wasn't size in `eax` like my initial guess but it was rather `i`

Comment: You might want to be more explicit about the undefined behavior and the tentative explanation for a specific CPU and compiler combination.  What you are describing is probably true but not guaranteed whatsoever.

Comment: @chqrlie it is not guaranteed, yes.  That is why I said I cannot know until OP pastes ```objdump -d```. I wanted to give a different perspective than its just garbage value and undefined behavior.

Comment: @chqrlie I may add example code later tho

Comment: @chqrlie: Neither is it true that “Anything is possible.” The C standard’s “undefined behavior” only removes any rules that the C standard imposes on the behavior, it does not remove any other rules, which is what would be necessary to make “Anything is possible” be true.

Comment: Check out [Godbolt's Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/9h1qodfTa). it is a great tool for experimenting with compilers and options.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Any value is possible, including the observed behavior. And on some exotic architectures, a trap value read by `main` might cause other strange behavior.